# Amazon Product Advertising API on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-product-api

What is the easiest way to use the Amazon Product API on the Google App Engine? How do you work around the socket limitations of Google App Engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using the [REST API](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=2478&categoryID=14) ?  If it's purely a REST API, you should be able to make calls using the urlfetch service.

What have you tried so far, and what errors has it given you?

Also, are you using the Java or Python version of App Engine?

Comment: I haven't tried much so far :-) I was hoping there would be a nice little library wrapping the API in either Python or Java that can be readily dropped in App Engine.

Comment: You'll have to talk to the creators of that library to address those issues. My point was that a REST API should absolutely be available in App Engine, because it's just a URL fetch.  If you don't find a wrapper for the API that works in App Engine, it should be easy enough to write your own.

Comment: OK, thanks. I am going to go with pyaws (which I got from here: http://bitbucket.org/IanLewis/pyaws/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/redtoad/python-amazon-product-api) together with [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) on App Engine. Had no problems so far.

Comment: you saved my day buddy. I already familiar with both of them. But, never clicked using this way. Referring to https://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api/src/b2ebc19a73ea/examples/using-xml-minidom.py may be helpful to others to replace default lxml parser to their own choice of xml parser.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-simple-product-api/1.4.0) basic Amazon Product API module is compatible with Google App Engine.